# How to access elements of array and vector repeatedly in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a vector of int V'

```
vector<int> V={2,4,5,6,7};
```

I want to iterate through vector such that if index is greater than size of vector it should return again some element in vector for example V.size() is 5 if I enter V[6] I need result to return 4,if I enter v[5] it should return 2.....
can I also do it with arrays??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: No, you cannot access an element of  either a vector or an array out of bounds.  For the behavior you want, you should create your own container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `array[]={2,4,5,6,7}`;

If you want to circle through array you could use **index mod sizeofarray**.

Let n be the index
//here size of array =5;

You could use `array[n% 5]` to acces elements.

so `array[6] => array[6 % 5] => array[1]= 4`

and same applies with **vector**.

Answer (score 2):

If you want accessing the values to "wrap around", then simply use the modulo operator when indexing.

That is to say: instead of `V[i]`, use `V[i % V.size()]`.

Comment: I wonder if you could subclass/override somehow to enforce such access?

Comment: by using this it won't return 4 if you enter 6.

Comment: @MartinJames: Of course it's possible. Is it worth it? No idea.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution that prompts for user input until the user inputs a number within the boundaries of the array...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    vector<int> vec{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}; // size 5

    int num = 0;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number between 0 and " << vec.size() - 1 << ": ";
        cin >> num;    

    } while (num < 0 || num >= vec.size());

    cout << "The vector value is: " << vec[num] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```